# Objective C Typwriter Effect

Tags: objective-c

How can this be done, I have been looking for quite some time now but have failed to find any efficient methods. I have to type a fair bit of text so making a gif image isn't the fastest/easiest way; not only that but I have no experience with creating GIF images.

Is there any way to create this effect with objective c?

Typewriter effect = Text gets displayed over a duration. 
1/2/3/4 = seconds

1: A
2: B
3: C
4: D

ABCD would then be displayed over four seconds.

Thank you!

EDIT: I am using Xcode5.

Comment: You didn't specify which platform you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *typewriter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger index;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.text = @"Testing...";
    self.index = 1;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(typeIt) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)typeIt{
    if( [self.text length] >= self.index )
    {
        self.typewriter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.text substringToIndex:self.index++]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: @J Shapiro, I have tried your method but it appears that not much happens. I have out in all the @properties but my label returns with either nothing or "Testing...".

Comment: Did you hook up the label from the Storyboard to the IBOutlet (typewriter)?

Comment: Thats embarrassing... I have now done so. You are a project saver J Shapiro.